# Unable to export Ad Hoc App Appcellerator Studio

Tags: ios, appcelerator

I am having issues with code signing the app, I have updated the Provisioning profile and the Distribution Certificates and then app seems to compile properly but then I get this error message:

```
[INFO] :   Removing files
[INFO] :   Optimizing .plist and .png files
[INFO] :   Invoking xcodebuild
[INFO] :   Packaging for Ad Hoc distribution
[ERROR] :  Failed to export archive to ipa
[ERROR] :  The selected provisioning profile "FFE W 4 (3c380e3b-7393-4f33-a64e-9de523ab2a53)" is most likely not a valid Ad Hoc provisioning profile.
[ERROR] :  Please ensure you are using a valid Ad Hoc provisioning that is linked to the signing identity, then try again.
```

I am running Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235) and Appcellerator Studio:

Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.9.1.201707200100
(c) Copyright 2012-2016 by Appcelerator, Inc.  All rights reserved.

Build: jenkins-appcelerator-studio-titanium_studio-master-46 (master)
Date: 20 July 2017, 01:00:49

and have tried the Titanium SDSK 6.1.2, 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I updated the Studio and the SDK and the app was able to be exported